# expand/collapse the row information with dynamic data

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ngtable

I am working on angularjs application. I want to expand/collapse table row and show more dynamic information when clicked on the image present in the table row.

Please find the demo : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/LjVTnKjaLdnYojqV?preview

WHen clicked on the tick mark present on the row, i want to show more details for that row. Currently with my demo above, it is expanding the row or collapsing when clicked on the image but issue is it is not showing the dynamic data information in the expanded row(newly shown row).

sample:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody ng-repeat="row in $data">
    <tr ng-click="show()">
      <td>
            <a class="btn btn-link" ng-init="toggle[$index] = false" ng-click="toggle[$index] = !toggle[$index]">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-if="!toggle[$index]"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed" ng-if="toggle[$index]"></span>
            </a>
          </td>

      <td data-title="'Name'">{{row.name}}</td>
      <td data-title="'Age'">{{row.age}}</td>
      <td data-title="'SID'">{{row.sid}}</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr ng-if="toggle[$index]">
      <div ng-table="tableParams2" ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td> {{$index}}</td>
          <td> {{product}}</td>
           <td> {{month}} </td>
            <td> {{pid}}</td>
      </div>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

js code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {

$scope.show = function(){
  alert("show/hide");
  var data = [{product: "TV", month: 5,pid:"11"},
              {product: "mobile", age: 4,pid:"22"},
              {product: "desktop", age: 7,pid:"33"}];
   $scope.tableParams2 = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});
}

var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Jacob", age: 27,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Nephi", age: 29,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Enos", age: 34,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Jacob", age: 27,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Nephi", age: 29,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Enos", age: 34,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Jacob", age: 27,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Nephi", age: 29,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Enos", age: 34,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Jacob", age: 27,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Nephi", age: 29,sid:"12PAX"},
              {name: "Enos", age: 34,sid:"12PAX"}];

$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed to the following, can't tell for certain but seems like ng-table had an issue with the `div` around the `td` elements, and may have had a problem being nested and referencing `$data` again? Maybe someone can comment with more knowledge.

.js

```
$scope.show = function(){
  alert("show/hide");
  $scope.tableParams2 = [{product: "TV", month: 5,pid:"11"},
              {product: "mobile", age: 4,pid:"22"},
              {product: "desktop", age: 7,pid:"33"}];
}
```

.html

```
<tr ng-if="toggle[$parent.$index]"ng-repeat="row in tableParams2">
      <td> {{$index}}</td>
      <td> {{row.product}}</td>
       <td> {{row.month}} </td>
        <td> {{row.pid}}</td>
</tr>
```

[My updated Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/mZNipZqZAhCAapay?preview)

Comment: How to show all the data present in tableParams2 (3 rows when clicked on each row image).currently it is showing only one row based on the index..@Gabriel Gates

Comment: Sorry, @nan did not notice that one, I updated the answer so that the `ng-if` uses the parent's `$index` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is still having some issue when data is retrieved based on some condition check(dynamic data).When clicked on first row image, data is shown correctly again when clicked on second row image, the dynamic data shown for second row is also shown in the first row, similarly when clicked on other rows the current data is shown in all the previous expanded rows.. Demo : next.plnkr.co/edit/kR9bDDbuVkby2ely?preview

Comment: Check out my updated plunker http://next.plnkr.co/edit/nJK3RJPqOMF4qF7O?preview your problem is because of `$scope.tableParams2` getting assigned a new value each time, and since that's what the others are referencing, they all update. You should go through a tutorial like https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 in order to get a better understanding of the AngularJS basics.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs and link, issue is i cannot give the static condition as if(input =='1'){ ..} if(input =='2'){..} as the data i'm getting is dynamic data when i click on the image in the row , when user click on image in first row, it gets the data from backend dynamically and display similarly for other row when clicked on the image it gets the data from backend and display..Is there any appropriate way?one thought i have is to hide the previous expanded row when user click on the new row to see information.. Is it possible? or is there any better approach?

Comment: Fetching the data dynamically from a backend should not be a problem, you could either fetch it all on page load then loop through the result set when you show the row, or you can call the backend individually each time you show the row.

Comment: Yes , I’m fetching from the database each time when I expand the row. But issue is as said above it is overriding the precious shown row information also with the new fetched value as now the $scope.tableparams2 contains newly fetched value . So how to avoid this situation? When I click on row1 image it is expanded and the details is shown again when I clicked on row2 image newly fetched data is shown in row2 as well as previously expanded row1 also overwritten with newly fetched value which should not be...

Comment: Any inputs on the above?

Comment: I thought I covered this part in the comment above, if you set `$scope.tableparams2` to be a different value, angular will rerender every instance of it in the HTML. As long as you return some sort of array from the backend you can loop over it and grab the value you want. For each row that you click, you will need a different `$scope` variable defined for each case, or an expression which returns what you want. Which I've already provided an example to http://next.plnkr.co/edit/nJK3RJPqOMF4qF7O?preview it sounds like you need to read some more Angular documentation and do some tutorials.